# Open Twitter Setting from ACAccountStore (iOS 5.1 TWITTER)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, twitter, ios5.1

in iOS 5.0 i was opening Twitter setting  from my app by

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];`

but , this features is removed in iOS 5.1 , hence i can not able to open twitter setting .

Now i am using

```
 + (void)makeRequestsWithURL: (NSURL *)url {
// Create an account store object.
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

// Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[self canTweetStatus];

// Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];


            // Create a request, which in this example, posts a tweet to the user's timeline.
            // This example uses version 1 of the Twitter API.
            // This may need to be changed to whichever version is currently appropriate.
            TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

            // Set the account used to post the tweet.
            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                iOS5Twitter *twitter5 = [[iOS5Twitter alloc] init];
                [twitter5 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
                [twitter5 release];                }];
        }
    }

}];
```

}

for making request, i am able to check wether i am loged in or not by the

`if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])`

but now i want : if i am not loged in it would be show an alert like shown in image and want to move to the twitter setting . is it possible ? or i have to manually go ti twitter setting ?[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is little tricky , i get by the removing the subviews  in `*TWTWeetComposeViewController*`, so it shows only alert when user is not loged in and by the clicking on setting button , we can open Setting page in my app.

```
     + (void)setAlertForSettingPage :(id)delegate 
    {
     // Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];


        // Create the completion handler block.
        [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            [delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];

        // Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
        [delegate presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
        //tweetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
        for (UIView *view in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

     }
```

here , deleate is your viewcontroller , if you are using this method inside your viewcontroller just use `self` instead of `delegate`.

Comment: How to avoid appearing of keyboard in above logic

Comment: @jeeva i think keyboard is not showing or if it is then just find textview or textfield by  (UIView *view in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
    } and make it resignFirstResponder.

Comment: If you are looking for something that works in iOS 6.0+ the answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325266/open-twitter-setting-from-acaccountstore-ios-5-1-twitter/13293846#13293846) worked great.

Comment: great trick, use the updated version below. this also gets credit for figuring it out in the first place though.

Comment: @jeeva deleting children views before presenting modal viewcontroller works for me.

Answer (score 8):

iOS 6 uses SLComposeViewController instead of TWTweetComposeViewController, so now you have to do this if you want it to work on iOS 6 and iOS 5:

```
    UIViewController *tweetComposer;

    if([SLComposeViewController class] != nil)
    {
        tweetComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [(SLComposeViewController *)tweetComposer setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
         {
            // do whatever you want
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        tweetComposer = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        [(TWTweetComposeViewController *)tweetComposer setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
         {
            // do whatever you want
         }];
    }

    for (UIView *view in [[tweetComposer view] subviews])
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    [self presentViewController:tweetComposer animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: this method is working fine, but when i return to my app a black shadow is still on screen. It is the background that appear when alert view to send user to Settings is not removed. Did you do something to avoid this?

Comment: Hmm, no, I don't have that issue. The [view removeFromSuperview] calls should get rid of all of them. Can you inspect the view hierarchy to see what is still being displayed?

Comment: Had the same issue with the black shadow - the remains of the UIViewController that was presented, I assume. Got around that by replacing the two occurrences above of // do whatever you want with              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Senior's and PJR's answers above, this is what worked for me.

Same as Senior's, except with a dimissViewController in the completion handler. For me this got around the problem that the empty view controller would stick around after I returned to the app from the settings. It would overlay my view controller and make it useless.

Brilliant solution, thanks Senior and PJR.

```
UIViewController *tweetComposer;

if([SLComposeViewController class] != nil)
{
    tweetComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [(SLComposeViewController *)tweetComposer setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
     {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
     }];
}
else
{
    tweetComposer = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [(TWTweetComposeViewController *)tweetComposer setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
     {
           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

     }];
}

for (UIView *view in [[tweetComposer view] subviews])
    [view removeFromSuperview];

[self presentViewController:tweetComposer animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the post view,
instead using this code:

```
for (UIView *view in [[tweetComposer view] subviews])
    [view removeFromSuperview];
```

use this:

```
tweetComposer.view.alpha = 0;
```

works both for twitter and facebook.