# Getting Twitter to display the option of going to my settings page if Twitter is not set up? iOS5+

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

If I access Twitter, I would prefer to use the automatic alert box asking that the user go to settings, yet can't get it to work and provide my own default dialog, which I really don't want to do.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"indexPath.row %i", indexPath.row);

if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; // Long-lived

    twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted) {
            // Access has been granted, now we can access the accounts

            twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];
            if (twitterAccounts.count == 1) {
                  [self getTwitterData:[twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0]];

            } else {
                   [self selectTwitterAccount];
            }
        } else {
        // Prefer NOT to do this ************************************
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showTwitterError) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is little tricky , i get by the removing the subviews  in `*TWTWeetComposeViewController*`, so it shows only alert when user is not loged in and by the clicking on setting button , we can open the setting page in my app.

```
     + (void)setAlertForSettingPage :(id)delegate 
    {
     // Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];


        // Create the completion handler block.
        [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            [delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];

        // Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
        [delegate presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
        //tweetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
        for (UIView *view in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

     }
```

Here, delegate is your viewcontroller, if you are using this method inside your viewcontroller just use `self` instead of `delegate`.

I had to face the same problem and found this [sollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325266/open-twitter-setting-from-acaccountstore-ios-5-1-twitter/)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this was only possible in iOS versions 5.0 - 5.0.1. 
It was then depreciated again in iOS 5.1

So NO solution at the moment...

In case you would like to use the iOS 5 part:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

And some [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application) reading on the same topic